# Changing field values on a attribute table using GDAL/OGR (ESRI Shapefile)?

Tags: qgis, gdal, shapefile, attribute-table, ogr

I am trying to create a new column on attribute table of my shapefile.
This table must be the `FID` formatted with 4 (or any number) digits (for instance: 0 = 0000, 1 = 0001, 2 = 0002...)

but I just can't, I must be missing something, I already take a look on other users codes and I cannot find my bug... My code just add a new column, but doesn't write anything...

```
def iterable_field_creator(shp_path, number=2 or 3 or 4):
    import ogr

    # Checking if parameter is a shp, create driver, datasource and layer
    if shp_path.endswith(".shp"):
        DriverName = "ESRI Shapefile"
        driver = ogr.GetDriverByName(DriverName)
        datasource = driver.Open(shp_path, 1) # 1 para escrever
        lyr = datasource.GetLayer()
        feature = lyr.GetNextFeature()
    else:
        print("\033[31mNOT A SHAPEFILE\033[m\n"
              "The program will be closed")
        quit()


    # Add new field on Att table (ID_it) 
    idField = ogr.FieldDefn("ID_it", ogr.OFTString)
    idField.SetWidth(number)
    lyr.CreateField(idField)

    ### I did try this way before
    # for features in lyr:
    #     fid = features.GetFID()
    #     id_it = formating_number(str(fid), number)
    #     feature = lyr.GetFeature(fid)
    #     print("The feature FID nº \033[31m{}\033[m will be called \033[33m{}\033[m on ID_it field!!!".format(
    #         fid, id_it))
    #     feature.SetField(id_it, "ID_it")
    # del features
    #

    while feature:
        fid = feature.GetFID()
        id_it = formating_number(str(fid), number)
        feature.SetField("ID_it", str(id_it))
        print("A feição de FID nº \033[31m{}\033[m terá o Identificador iterável de código \033[33m{}\033[m!!!".format(
            fid, id_it))
        feature = lyr.GetNextFeature()

    datasource.Destroy()

    osgeo = None
    ogr = None
    lyr= None
    driver = None
    DriverName = None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything was almost ok, I've reformatted back to for loop (your for loop had unnecessary  "feature = lyr.GetFeature(fid)" line). The most important part was adding

```
lyr.SetFeature(feature)
```

in the loop to preserve changes

```
def iterable_field_creator(shp_path, number=2 or 3 or 4):

    import ogr

    # Checking if parameter is a shp, create driver, datasource and layer
    if shp_path.endswith(".shp"):
        DriverName = "ESRI Shapefile"
        driver = ogr.GetDriverByName(DriverName)
        datasource = driver.Open(shp_path, 1)  # 1 para escrever
        lyr = datasource.GetLayer()

    else:
        print("\033[31mNOT A SHAPEFILE\033[m\n"
              "The program will be closed")
        quit()

    # Add new field on Att table (ID_it)
    idField = ogr.FieldDefn("ID_it", ogr.OFTString)
    idField.SetWidth(number)
    lyr.CreateField(idField)

    for feature in lyr:  #reformatted
        fid = feature.GetFID()
        id_it = formatting_number(fid, number)
        feature.SetField("ID_it", str(id_it))
        lyr.SetFeature(feature)  #added in order to save field value

    datasource.Destroy()

    osgeo = None
    ogr = None
    lyr = None
    driver = None
    DriverName = None
```

Comment: Thank you very much! My code is working right now!

Comment: @ConsalterR-1988 great, consider [accepting](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) this answer

Comment: For sure! it is done. Sorry, i am a newby here. Thank you very much for warn me about it!